# Regex OR Condition

Tags: regex

Currently I have this formula:

```
(var file = '(.*?)';|var e="(.*?)")
```

I am trying to find everything between `var file = '` and `';`. OR Everything between `var e="` and `"`.

I am using a `|` for the OR condition. But when I execute the formula for either of the two data sections below, it ends up returning: "home.jsonnull" or "nullhcp-home". **I don't want the null.**

I am using a custom regex extraction on Screaming Frog to crawl this site: https://hcp.eylea.us. I want it to return hcp-home.

**Potential data 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var file = 'home.json';
    if (file !== undefined && file.length > 0) {
        var fullFile = '/Content/json-schema/' + file;
        $.get(fullFile, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            $('body').append(data);
        }, "text");
```

**Potential data 2:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){var e="hcp-home";if(e.length>0){$.get("/content/json-schema/"+e+".json",function(e,n,t){$("body").append(e)},"text")}});
```

Comment: well I can tell you that `(.?)` is only going to contain either 0 or 1 characters. I think you might want to use `+` which designates 1 or more

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to run the regex?

Comment: The asterisk I had in the original comment turned into an italics. I updated the formula. I am currently running this through Screaming Frog as a Regex custom extraction.

Comment: ah I think I see what is happening. Your program is trying to print all 3 of the capture groups you have (each set of parentheses is a group). Thats why it is printing null, only one of the groups has text matched within it. Try something like this `(var file = '.*?';|var e=".*?")`

Comment: What regex engine (the program) are you using?

Comment: Katamari is the closest so far. It is pulling as: var file = 'home.json';  Is there a way to only get the home.json?

Comment: Have you checked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634396/3832970)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your regex to support both single and double quotes. Using the following regex, you can get the Whole match as well as content between quotes:

```
/var (?:file = |e=)['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"]/
```

The regex starts matching 'var ' followed by 'file =' or 'e=' followed by a quote, then matches everything not being a quote (non greedy) and finally a quote. 
It does this for '`var file`' as well as '`var e`'.

To get the content between quotes you use Group 1.